# Join CSV file to shapefile in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, attribute-joins, error-000728

I am trying to join a shapefile and a CSV file. I have tried Arcpy.AddJoin_management... the error message I receive is that there is no field name for the CSV file.

I tried to index it and same error message shows up.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env


env.workspace = "E:\county"    
in_data = "county.shp"
out_data = "E:\county\County2.shp"
data_type = ""

arcpy.Copy_management(in_data, out_data, data_type)    
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("E:\\county\\County2.shp")
arcpy.MakeTableView_management ("E:\county\data.csv")

LayerName = "County_Layer" 
Field = "NAME"
TableName = "data_View"
Field2 = "County"

arcpy.AddJoin_management (LayerName, Field, TableName, Field2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    arcpy.AddJoin_management (LayerName, Field, TableName, Field2)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6066, in AddJoin
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000728: Field County does not exist within table
Failed to execute (AddJoin).
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A question asking for help with code should include a snippet of the code you have tried, and details about what happens when you try it and where you are stuck.  Please **[edit]** your question to include your code snippet and any other relevant information.

Comment: A sample/screenshot of your csv and details of your shapefile would be useful also.

Comment: Please also [edit] your question to include your error message in full including all line numbers mentioned

Comment: Have you tried the join using the GUI through the table of contents?

Comment: @SteveC No I haven't

Comment: You might try working through the table of contents to perform the join.  Add the csv to the project and use the join tool.

Comment: `NAME` is probably a reserved field name. Try changing the field name to something else before you do the join. I'd suggest trying the join in ArcMap and validating it to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Import the csv to a file geodatabase

Comment: My table name is a generic `table_View1`, but this process fails with error 000840: `line 6066, in AddJoin     raise e ExecuteError: The value cannot be a feature class ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer. `. So how can you perform a join if your table is not among the list of objects allowed? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The path you use in your `MakeTableView` statement is incorrect. Python will not interpret the single backslash in your path string correctly. You can use any of these to represent a file path string:

- `r"E:\county\data.csv"`
- `"E:\\county\\data.csv"`
- `"E:/county/data.csv"`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. After correcting it, the same error message still shows up.

Comment: Just noticed the same problem on lines 4 & 7. Please edit the code in your original post as you correct them.